# Weblogic - web application within main application

Tags: java, weblogic

I've been provided solution files that are effectively represented by the following, where "/" is the root for the web application:

```
/ (potentially a shared application)
/WEB-INF
/META-INF
/appName
/appName/apps (actual website files and content)
/appName/conf (certain site confirgurations)
```

I can successfully create a deployment based on the root of this application, but i need it to reference the /appName/apps/ folder when viewing the sites URL, for demonstration call it: localhost:7004.

If I call the URL localhost:7004 i effectively get a 404. If i call localhost:7004/appName/apps files are served but much of the referencing is wrong (relative and absolute referencing conflict).

I need a way so calling the localhost:7004 URL serves content from the /appName/apps folder by default. Is there a way to achieve this within WebLogic?

I'm fairly new to the workings of WebLogic so i appologise if I'm not clear in the description of my issues. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to enter the base URL to access your application rather than specifying the full URL, you will want to set the `context-root`:

Edit `weblogic.xml` in your deployment and add the following entry as needed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<context-root>/</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

The `/` here just means that your webapp will be assigned to the root level URL.

See weblogic docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1073750

See another useful example here:
http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=886

Comment: so presumably setting the Context-Root to /appName/apps/ should solve my problem right? I've tried this previously but it did not work, I will try again though.

Comment: whilst I was, and still am convinced something like this is the right approach, when using it I just get 404 errors when trying to view localhost:7004 with the conext-root set to /appName/apps/.

when it's set to / the website will only load when /appName/apps/ is included as part of the URL.

Comment: presumably actually using appName/apps/ in the context is the reverse of what i wish to achieve? i.e. My required URL would become localhost:7004/appName/apps/appName/apps/

Comment: using a context root or "/" means, to access the site files in the appName/apps/ folder i need appName/apps/ as part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was not a result of WebLogic setup, but rather Web Server configuration. My context root remained as "/".

In IIS (I assume the same for Apache) I needed to set up a "PathPrepend" for my appName/apps/ folder. this resolved the issue.